# What is the nature of the $residuals element of the output of lm? Can i capture its indexes (or psuedo-indexes)?

Tags: r

[outval, below, is the returned result from lm()].

Note how the residuals vector in this regression output are displayed.
(rows 2 and 4 have been eliminated from the regression as they contain missing values)

**Is there a way i can capture those numbers that appear in the output as displayed for outval$residuals (1, 3, 5, 6) into another vector? That is what i want to do.**

Here are some things i looked at but could not discover how to accomplish capture of 1, 3, 5, 6!

```
Browse[1]> outval$residuals
         1          3          5          6
 0.7457627 -0.7966102 -1.3389831  1.3898305
```

Those indices (1,3,5,6) are not really the indices of the $residuals vector. As shown below, the vector appears to be indexed by 1,2,3,4.

```
Browse[1]> outval$residuals[1]
        1
0.7457627
Browse[1]> outval$residuals[2]
         3
-0.7966102
Browse[1]> outval$residuals[3]
        5
-1.338983
Browse[1]> outval$residuals[4]
       6
1.389831
Browse[1]> outval$residuals[5]
<NA>
  NA
```

I thought maybe it was a table-like entity with 2 rows and 4 columns, but it cannot be accessed that way.

```
Browse[1]> outval$residuals[1,1]
Error in outval$residuals[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Although outval$residuals[4] appears to have 2 elements present when displayed (above) (a "6" and "1.338983"), its length is only 1.

```
Browse[1]> length (outval$residuals[4])
[1] 1
```

Comment: `outval$residuals` is a named vector. You can get the values above with `names(outval$residuals)` or values below with `unname(outval$residuals)`

Comment: Or `as.numeric(names(outval$residuals))` if you want a numeric vector

Comment: Yes, this is my solution, the names() function. I don't know how to mark it as the solution though, don't see a place to do that so i add this comment.  Thank you very much!